# How can I pass variables meant for a trigger function in SQLite?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

```
/* 
// this is the trigger definition
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER 'insertTrigger' INSTEAD OF INSERT ON 'foo' 
BEGIN 
    SELECT bar(NEW.id, NEW.timestamp); "
END; 
//*/

void insert(sqlite3 *db, char *id, char *timestamp, void *context){
    exec_query(db, "INSERT INTO foo(id,timestamp) VALUES(?,?)", id, timestamp);
}

void bar(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv){
    char *id = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
    char *timestamp = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[1]);
    //how do I get context* ???
    //this must be a thread safe function (i.e. multiple threads have their own sqlite3* and all execute queries (possibly including this one)
}
```

Is there some workaround to enable this? Just as an idea:

```
void insert(sqlite3 *db, char *id, char *timestamp, void *context){
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
    sqlite3_user_setdata(db, context); //this doesnt exist
    exec_query(db, "INSERT INTO foo(id,timestamp) VALUES(?,?)", id, timestamp);
    sqlite3_mutex_leave(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
}

void bar(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv){
    char *id = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
    char *timestamp = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(argv[1]);
    void *context_ = sqlite3_user_data(context);
}
```

There are a few other methods it seems that might be able to accomplish this such as the `sqlite3_get_auxdata` functions, but I dont really understand how that api works.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Are you using C or C++? Please remove the other tag.

Comment: @ThiefMaster the question applies to both languages.

Comment: @chacham15 Then it should be two separate questions. Just having a quick first glance at the code, there are `void *`s in it. That in itself is a good reason to treat it **a radically different way** in the two languages.

Comment: @H2CO3 No, I dont want to treat it any differently. The code needs to work in both c and c++.

Comment: @chacham15 It doesn't matter whether or not you want -- you will **have to,** since C and C++ are two distinct languages with a long list of differences in semantics. Unfortunately, they happen to share a common *syntactic* subset, and that makes some people (for example you) believe that either C is a subset of C++ or that C code works in the same manner when compiled as C++, neither of which is true.

Comment: @H2CO3 dude, dont assume that you know what I know (and that you know it all). Despite the fact that C is not a proper subset of C++, you can write code using common features of both and not go outside those bounds. This is legitimate  beyond a shadow of a doubt and I dont want to argue that with you.

Comment: @chacham15 Don't assume that I don't know what I am talking about. I know that one can write code that can be processed as both C and C++, but that's an edge case and madness. And it doesn't change the fact that **in general,** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`context` is not part of your query so it will not be available in the trigger function.

After all, the SQL statement you send to update your table might (should) not know about the triggers at all!

Comment: Yes, but look at the update to see an idea of how this might be done (even though the particular suggestion doesnt work).